# Choose the start page of a material

Tags: page

I prepare a book of short stories. There are no too long texts, each story takes no more than two pages. The customer asks to layout two-paged stories in such a way that they would be placed starting from an even page.

Now I've written a command that layouts a box of the title of a story and a box of full text of the story. The if their total height is greater than the height of the page, the current page number is checked and a page is skipped if necessary. Afterwards, the material is put: for the title its box is used, but the text is made up again.

In this scheme, the text is made up twice: at first, when I compute the height it takes, and at second, when it actually prepared for layout. Is it possible to optimize the process somehow?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Showing your code in a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) would certainly help optimizing it.

Comment: So where should a story start that is not longer than one page? Doesn't matter or always on next page or also on even pages?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the value of the page number, and add blank pages as needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\storytitle}[1]{%
  \clearpage% Move to next page
  \ifodd\value{page} \mbox{}\clearpage\fi% If page is odd, move to next page
  \section*{#1}% Set story title/heading
}

\begin{document}

\storytitle{First story}
\lipsum[1-7]

\storytitle{Second story}
\lipsum[8-10]

\storytitle{Third story}
\lipsum[11-16]

\storytitle{Last story}
\lipsum[17-24]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would it not be better to use either `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` in the `if`?

Comment: @OlegLobachev: If you're using the `twoside` option, then the pages will be cleared to an odd page. So you'll have to do some work correcting for that either way.